# Base consecutive k-frequency counter

Tags: base-conversion

Given a base \$k\$ as well as two indices (also passed in base \$k\$, call them \$s\$ and \$e\$) return a list containing a frequency count of all base-\$k\$ digits occurring between \$s\$ and \$e\$ inclusive. For example, upon input \$k = 10, s = 1, e = 10\$, we would return the list \$[0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4:1, 5:1, 6:1 , 7:1, 8:1, 9:1]\$. Note that the values in the list should be base \$k\$ as well.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Code Golf! I like the challenge, but have a few questions: (1) What is the set of characters which should be used for bases larger than 36? (Or is \$k \leq 36\$?)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange. Your challenge is quite good, but it could do with a few clarifications, like the comment made by @97.100.97.109 . It is reccomended to post challenges in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first.

Comment: Let's assume \$k \leq 36\$. I will modify my challenge if you can provide me with a good base system for \$k > 36\$.

Comment: I think this needs to be much clearer about the strict I/O requirements. For what it's worth I don't think the "characters" question really addresses things, it's a question from someone who planned to use a string representation for their I/O. Sure, IF one is going to use a string of characters there is a limit, but really a base-k number is a list of integers from \$[0,k)\$. Would also be a good idea to show an example in a base other than ten (probably a higher base would show things best).

Comment: I didn't notice until now (...), but this challenge doesn't have a scoring criteria (like [tag:code-golf]). Please consider adding one (otherwise it would be off-topic :p)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 75 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 9.375 bytes

```
vβ÷ṡ⁰τfĊ⁰τ
```

Accepts input as \$[s, e], k\$. Takes in indices as a list of digits (to be able to take numbers of bases greater than 10).

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwids6yw7fhuaHigbDPhGbEiuKBsM+EIiwiIiwiW1syXSwgWzEsIDIsIDFdXVxuMyJd) | [Another example](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwids6yw7fhuaHigbDPhGbEiuKBsM+EIiwiIiwiW1s1XSwgWzEsIDE0LCAxM11dXG4xNiJd)

Bitstring:

```
100011000100010100000110110111110010011010110100010011110011110110000110010
```

```
vβ÷ṡ⁰τfĊ⁰τ
vβ          Convert each index to base 10
  ÷ṡ        Split to stack and push range
    ⁰τ      Convert range to base k
      fĊ    Flatten list and push counts
        ⁰τ  Convert counts list to base k
```

Comment: Hi- your code doesn't fully satisfy the end "values in base k" property. The example you've provided outputs ⟨ ⟨ 2 | 10 ⟩ | ⟨ 1 | 19 ⟩ | ⟨ 0 | 8 ⟩ ⟩ while I want the values (i.e. 10, 19, 8) to be in base 3 as well.

Comment: @MichaelKlyachman oh, missed that part.

Comment: I realised I could take all numbers as a list of digits to make the input format more strict. (and, shaving off some bits in the process :d)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 163 bytes

```python
def f(k,s,e):b=lambda n:n and b(n//k).lstrip("0")+[str(n%k),chr(n%k+55)][n%k>9]or"0";a="".join(map(b,range(int(s,k),int(e,k)+1)));return{c:b(a.count(c))for c in a}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9BCsIwEEWvEgLCDI3VLgSt6EXERZImWquTkqYLEU_iRhC9gYfxNo6Ki4EH_394c3m0x7QNdL3e--SH09etcl54aFSnHJZmsdcHU2lBJQlNlTBAo1GD-b5LsW5BjiVmK2agQYPKbr-QTSa4XjEsZ-sQuTPXCynzXagJDroFo6KmjYOaEnSKdx9wDFmBiPPoUh_pZEsDOreh59Ai-hCFFTVrnH-qzzZ-dh6KsZKF5GMZ_GX_d94)

Basic solution; a majority of the code is taken up by the helper function converting from base 10 to base \$k\$. I'm sure you could do something clever with a function which directly counts from \$s\$ to \$e\$ in base \$k\$. Only works for bases between 2 and 36.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 80 bytes

```ruby
->k,s,e{(s.to_i(k)..e.to_i(k)).flat_map{_1.digits k}.tally.map{[_1,_2.to_s(k)]}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3A3TtsnWKdVKrNYr1SvLjMzWyNfX0UmFMTb20nMSS-NzEgup4Q72UzPTMkmKF7Fq9ksScnEo9kHB0vKFOvBFIfTFQfWxtLdRc4wKFtGhDAx0lQyUgNlCK5QIJGOsoGYH4RoZQAUMzHSVTkEhqilIsROuCBRAaAA)

Takes `k` as integer, `s` and `e` as strings in base `k`. Test cases taken from math scat's [Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266415/78274).

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 148 bytes

```haskell
import Data.List
k#n|n<k=[n]
k#n|(d,m)<-divMod n k=m:k#d
f k s e=[(last(show x:[[toEnum$x+55]|x>9]),1+length y)|x:y<-group$sort$concatMap(k#)[s..e]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY89jsIwFIR7TvGkpLAXEi1CIIgSKuiWE1guLJIQy_FzFL9AkHIMOhqa1Z5pb7P8LM3oK0b6Zq4_lfKmqOvb7bujMlr-XrRtXEuwUaTiL-1pZAIcMDWZQPlklk8sT6NcH3cuBwST2cQE-agEAx6KTLBaeWK-cifoEyHIbbGzYT-ez-XQr1eST6bjusADVXDmQ5-c0-jQuq4J_V0c7h3uFe1Uw0zAhY_jQsr_bYFVGiGDptVIEEIJswV8ArvnxwMjmPJX9X3nDw)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 228 bytes

`=let(_,lambda(v,base(v,A1)),r,query(tocol(sort(to_text(split(regexreplace(join(,map(sequence(A3-A2+1,1,A2),_)),"(.)","$1 ")," ")))),"select count(Col1),Col1 group by Col1 label count(Col1)''",0),{map(index(r,,1),_),index(r,,2)})`

Put the base in cell `A1`, start in `A2` and end in `A3`, and the formula in `C1`.

The same ungolfed:

```
=let( 
  _, lambda(v, base(v, A1)), 
  values, sequence(A3 - A2 + 1, 1, A2), 
  string, join(, map(values, _)), 
  digits, tocol(sort(to_text(split(regexreplace(string, "(.)", "$1 "), " ")))), 
  result, query( 
    digits, 
    "select count(Col1), Col1 group by Col1 label count(Col1)''", 
    0 
  ), 
  hstack( 
    map(index(result, , 1), _), 
    index(result, , 2) 
  ) 
)
```

| parameters |  | results |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | base | C | 0 |
| 1 | start | 1D | 1 |
| 200 | end | 1D | 2 |
|  |  | 1D | 3 |
|  |  | 1D | 4 |
|  |  | 1D | 5 |
|  |  | 1D | 6 |
|  |  | 1D | 7 |
|  |  | 1D | 8 |
|  |  | 1C | 9 |
|  |  | 1C | A |
|  |  | 1C | B |
|  |  | 15 | C |
|  |  | C | D |
|  |  | C | E |
|  |  | C | F |